# MVC 3 Passing Data From HTML to Controller to Another Controller via HTTPPOST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, parameter-passing

I don't know if I'm doing this wrong, but here's my problem. I need to pass a `View`'s data to another `Controller/Action`.

In my HTML Form, I have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Preprocess", "Item", FormMethod.Post))
{
   ...some html...
   ...loop for each item in Items collection
   <button type="submit" name="itemInfo" value="@Model.someValue">Submit</submit>
}
```

I receive the Form's data on my `Item/Preprocess` Action (strongly-typed view). However, I need to pass this to a 'central processor' that process the data depending on a certain flag. How do I pass the values I receive on this controller to another controller? I'm a beginner in MVC and I'm not even sure if this is the right way to do it.

Basically, I have three HTML forms similar from the above form, but with different `Controllers` and `Views`. I need them to call a single central master-`Controller/Action` and of course pass the data from the Form to the master `Controller` via `HTTPPOST`. Of course, each `Controller` has to format its own data to a class the master `Controller` can accept. What should I put in place of `Return View()` or `RedirectToAction(...)`?

Can you guys suggest a way to do this?

Or maybe you guys can suggest another way. It may not follow what I want, but basically my requirement is a central Controller/Action (or some other Centralized code) can receive the data and do operations depending on a value

Comment: to pass data from view to controller use `Model`, and to pass data from one controller to another you can use `TempData`

Comment: How do you pass the TempData? Should I just redirect to the master `Controller` after setting the values in `TempData`?

Comment: TempData is not intended to be used for passing complex objects between controller actions.

Comment: I guess for this example, I just need to pass simple `strings`

Comment: It's the same. Not intended for this. You could use TempData to show some confirmation message or something when redirecting and don't care about the user pressing F5 to reload the page and seeing this data vanish away. So don't use TempData for this. Store the model somewhere on your server (a database or something) and then simply redirect to a controller action passing the id that will allow it to retrieve the model back. That's how stateless applications should be designed.

Comment: to use TempData, use it as you use Sessions(i mean syntax wise) eg :`TempData["myKey"]` and then read this from another controller

Comment: @Yasser, no, don't do this. No TempData please. What will happen if the user simply hits F5 to refresh the target web page? A NRE?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Here we are using purely a web service, and we have no database access whatsoever (the client cannot provide the database).

Comment: Then use the web service to persist the data. Just add methods to it that will persist and retrieve the data. But actually why not directly posting to the target controller action directly from the view? Why do you need to do redirects in the first place?

Comment: The web service is not ours, its a third party WS, so I can't modify it. I need this complex setup (or another simple one if you guys can suggest) because a single Controller/Action should perform the operation. And the data comes from 3 different Controllers (not relevant, but different view and viewmodels). All the data are the same for those 3 Controllers and Views except for a single Flag that lets the Master `Controller` figure out what to do with the data

Comment: Or maybe you guys can suggest another way. It may not follow what I want, but basically my requirement is a central Controller/Action (or some other Centralized code) can receive the data and do operations depending on a value

Comment: Sorry I don't understand at all what you are trying to achieve :-) Good luck with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController",new { id=someString} );
```

Comment: But `RedirectToAction` is a `GET` request, am I right? I need to use `POST` if possible

Comment: You cannot redirect to a POST action. A redirect means GET. That's the very basic definition of a redirect.

Comment: I guess I'm using the wrong term, but basically, after a `POST` it calls up (not redirect, but sort of redirects to another controller) another `Controller`

Comment: @Devmonster I thought that you want to post to a "central" action and that action call the corresponding Controller/Action. Am I right?

Comment: @Pabloker Yes. But I need to hide the values, or avoid exposing the values in the URL, as the user may play around with the data (e.g. `Controller/Action/232` and change that to another value). As a security measure (I guess), I need to use `POST` so that the values are transferred without the user seeing the data

Comment: Im not following: the main principle is GET(Load,read) -> POST (write,save) -> REDIRECT (refresh,show saved changes...). if you need to hide the ids the only thing that come to my mind is TempData but that is not its function... and that kind of tampering must be validated by the controller, like (do this user own 232? or has privileges to manipulate 232 if not REDIRECT)

Comment: As a side note: posting does not prevent a mildly competent user from seeing/changing the data.  Don't rely on it for security at all.  Anyone who can download fiddler can mess with your data and post whatever they want.

Comment: @Devmonster `POST` is not a security measure, you still have to protect everything on server side. And if you do that, you may as well switch to `GET` which will be so much easier to implement.

Comment: Yes I know that you can't rely on it for security, but at least it's another layer (as opposed to GET which a user can easily change the data in the URL. POST will take a lot longer). In addition to that, we will be using SSL throughout the whole site. GET is way too easy to manipulate, and you can perform a Request Forgery attack on a GET statement that directly exposes methods outside the web app. Actually, that was what I was trying to prevent - an XSRF

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow exactly what you are trying to do here.  But from your description it does sound like your design is wrong.

If you are trying to perform some common set of actions once data is received and processed by your controllers then you should promote your "central controller" to be some kind of service class that can be accessed by all three controllers.  The service class could return a ActionResult if necessary:

```
return new ViewResult { ViewName = "MyForm" };
```

However if you want to intercept the data and perform some common actions you could write a custom [ActionFilter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) to do whatever your central controller is doing and leave the other controllers clean.

Comment: Yes, I figured this complex a design means something's wrong. I was toying with the idea of a central controller to be a class instead, but that class needs to return a `View` in case a certain flag is set. It's like it needs to display a Form for additional information where a user can select an item so it can proceed with the process.

Comment: That's fine, just have your class return a return a ViewResult and return that result from your controller.  I've added an example to my answer.